# I can't initialize a non nullable variable class Position in flutter

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I am new to flutter and am simply trying to use the geolocator package.  I'm trying to initialize the Position class and nothing will work.  I've tried to set it equal to a list of variables, I've tried adding late to the prefix, I've tried adding ? to the end of Position. Any help would be appreciated.

Position _newPosition;

error:Non-nullable instance field '_newPosition' must be initialized.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong when you don't show exactly what you did.  The linked answer should help though.

Comment: use ,    Late Position _newPosition;

Comment: I'm trying to create a variable called _newPosition with the Position class.  As stated in the original question adding Late before the line does not work.